# Find string made up of maximum number of other strings

Tags: string, performance, algorithm, language-agnostic

Given an array of strings, find the string which is made up of maximum number of other
strings contained in the same array.

```
> e.g. “rat”, ”cat”, “abc”, “xyz”, “abcxyz”, “ratcatabc”, “xyzcatratabc”
> 
> Answer: “xyzcatratabc”
> 
> “abcxyz” contains 2 other strings,
> 
> “ratcatabc” contains 3 other strings,
> 
> “xyzcatratabc” contains 4 other strings
```

**I have come up with a O(n* ( Avgg_length_of_string^2 ) ) solution , employing DP.**

**Make up al possible breaks at every possible substring of a string, and check for maximality**. **Memoizing will give us the required complexity.**

Is there any other **Optimal(time bound)** way to solve this.

Comment: What will your algorithm return for `{"abc", "cde", "efg", "abcdefg"}`? More specifically, how would it know to take `"abc"` and `"efg"`, but not to take `"cde"`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i m not sure if i follow you .

Comment: First, I would like to check that I understood the problem correctly: what is the answer to the problem from my example? I assumed that it is 2 (`"abc"` and `efg"`). I am also trying to see if I understood your solution correctly. You suggested extracting all possible substrings from a string, and then "check for maximality" with memoization. How will you organize the check for maximality so that it solves my example correctly?

Comment: How many are all possible breaks in every possible substring of a string? Number of substrings of all the strings alone is O(n*m^2) and now we have an additional factor to multiply by "all possible breaks".

Comment: @chill please see this link for the implementation i am talking about.http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-32-word-break-problem/

Comment: @dasblinkenlight please see above link . It's xplained very well over there.

Comment: The explanation there is incorrect in describing the algorithm as dynamic programming. Dynamic programming involves overlapping problems (check) and optimality principle, which is not relevant for the task, which asks for mere existence, not, for example, for the split of the string in the maximum possible number of dictionary words.

Comment: @chill yes offcourse.But the above idea can be easily modified to find maximum breaks,which we need here.

Comment: So, the algorithm checks every possible break in every possible *suffix* of a string, which quite different from breaking every possible substring of a string.

Comment: @chill it essentially is the same thing.For every prefix, we see,if we already have a dictionary valid prefix,we see if we can xtend it further.

Comment: @Spandan The explanation is indeed very good, but it explains a solution to a *different* problem: their solution would not necessarily use the largest number of available words for the coverage, and there is no clear way to modify it so that it would.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes offcourse,but a slight modification will give us needfull.

Answer (score 1):

The [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) requires O(m) to create the tree, where m is the total length of all strings. Searching each string requires O(n + z), where n is the length of the string and z is the number of matches found. So it looks like you can do it in `O((2 * total_string_length) + number_of_matches)`.

It will, however, require O(m) extra memory for the tree.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You'd have to post process the matches for each string in order to check for overlaps.